# Can the dispatch values of a clojure multimethod be queried?

Tags: clojure

I'm writing some code that looks like this:

```
(def
  authorized-access-levels
  {:sales-rep-manager (fn [{{user :user} :session}]

                        )
   :regional-sales-manager (fn [{{user :user} :session}]

                             )
   :vp-of-sales (fn [{{user :user} :session}]

                  )
   })
```

Later in the code:

```
(defn
  get-my-housing
  [{{user :user} :session :as request}]
  (let [data-fn (authorized-access-levels (user :access-level))]
    (data-fn request)))
```

This at surface level seems like a great use case for multi methods where the `defmulti` would look like this:

```
(defmulti get-my-housing (fn [{{{access-level :access-level} :user} :session}] access-level))
(defmethod get-my-housing :vp-of-sales [{{user :user} :session}]

  )
```

but I have another need that looks like this:

```
:auth-fn (fn [user] (contains? authorized-access-levels (user :access-level)))
```

So (long story short) I need the keys to determine if a user is authorized to get data but then I use the key to dispatch to a function via a map.

Can I query a multimethod to see what it's dispatch values are? If so then I can write this as a multimethod and then query it for authorization. Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you give an example of how you want to call this function, and what the outputs should be for different inputs?

Comment: I updated the question. Hopefully that is more clear.

Comment: So you want to dispatch on the value for :access-level, and at the same time check that it is among a set of approved values?

Comment: First I want to see if the user is authorized (ie: in the set of allowed values) then, if authorized, run the appropriate function for that users access level. One challenge is that the authorization and execution actions happen at two different times so I can't just try the method to see if they are authorized.

Comment: Then you should be able to check that in the dispatch function, and have a separate method for :unauthorized, or something similar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can I query a multimethod to see what it's dispatch values are?

Yes, you can do introspection on a multimethod using the `methods` function to get the dispatch table for a multimethod, and the `get-method` to look up the method for a given dispatch value.

```
user=> (defmulti authorized? :access-level)
user=> (defmethod authorized? :admin [_] true)
user=> (defmethod authorized? :user [_] false)

user=> (keys (methods authorized?))
(:user :admin)

user=> ((get-method authorized? :admin) {:access-level :admin})
true
```

Comment: For existence testing, what's the performance like on `get-method` vs `(contains? (set (keys (methods my-multimethod)))`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly but let me try. You have three different concepts that we want to model as three different functions: get a users access-level, get a users authorization from the access level, and finally get the housing. I would model it like this:

```clj
(defn get-access-level [user]
  (:access-level user))

(defn authorized? [user]
  (contains? authorized-access-levels (get-access-level user)))

(defmulti get-my-housing (fn [req] 
                           (get-access-level (get-in req [:session :user]))

(defmethod get-my-housing :vp-of-sales
  [req]
  ((:vp-of-sales authorized-access-levels) req))
```

This is worth it if each `defmethod` has a different behavior. If they all access the same map with a different key the extra indirection is probably not worth it.